# How to fix crashes due to ProGuard/R8?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

I am making a simple app and it works perfectly, but when I try to shrink/obfuscate the code using ProGuard, it crashes when I open an Activity from another.

This also happens when using R8.

The full flow is:

Enter MainActivity, then spawn CameraActivity which uses Firebase MLKit for detecting Barcodes (this uses camera, of course). When a QR code is detected, it launches a DetailActivity which sends a request to server (uses Retrofit). The response is saved to DB using Room. Overall the app uses the whole Architecture Components.

It crashes in the transition from CameraActivity to DetailActivity, and there are absolutely no logs regarding the crash in the logcat.

The full source code can be found in https://github.com/gincos/bookqr-uc/tree/dev

You can inspect there my proguard-rules and my dependencies, most of the app is made in Kotlin and uses coroutines.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these in your proguard-rules and just follow the instructions on your logcat:

```
-addconfigurationdebugging
-dontobfuscate
```